# Can I register a new domain name in owner's name, with the invoice in my business name?

Tags: domain-registration, ownership

Is it possible - and how? - to register a new domain name in the owner's name, with the invoice in my business name? I would want to continue this arrangement on each extension of domain registration.

In case this is relevant, the domain would probably be .COM.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The domain owner and how the registration is paid for are two separate things.

> ... and how?

There is nothing special you need to do, just enter your payment details at "checkout".

If you find a domain registrar that imposes such a strange restriction (although I never have), then find a different registrar.